# How to reload tensorflow model in Google Cloud Run server?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, fastapi, distributed-system

I have a webserver hosted on cloud run that loads a tensorflow model from cloud file store on start. To know which model to load, it looks up the latest reference in a psql db.

Occasionally a retrain script runs using google cloud functions. This stores a new model in cloud file store and a new reference in the psql db.

Currently, in order to use this new model I would need to redeploy the cloud run instance so it grabs the new model on start. **How can I automate using the newest model instead?** Of course something elegant, robust, and scalable is ideal, but if something hacky/clunky but functional is much easier that would be preferred. This is a throw-away prototype but it needs to be available and usable.

I have considered a few options but I'm not sure how possible either of them are:

1. Create some sort of postgres trigger/notification that the cloud run server listens to. Guess this would require another thread. This ups complexity and I'm unsure how multiple threads works with Cloud Run.
2. Similar, but use a http pub/sub. Make an endpoint on the server to re-lookup and get the latest model. Publish on retrainer finish.
3. could deploy a new instance and remove the old one after the retrainer runs. Simple in some regards, but seems riskier and it might be hard to accomplish programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current pattern should implement cache management (because you cache a model). How can you invalidate the cache?

- Restart the instance? Cloud Run doesn't allow you to control the instances. The easiest way is to redeploy a new revision to force the current instance to stop and new ones to start.
- Setting a TTL? It's an option: load a model for XX hours, and then reload it from the source. Problem: you could have glitches (instances with new models and instances with the old one, up to the cache TTL expires for all the instances)
- Offering cache invalidation mechanism? As said before, it's hard because Cloud Run doesn't allow you to communicate with all the instances directly. So, push mechanism is very hard and tricky to implement (not impossible, but I don't recommend you to waste time with that). Pull mechanism is an option: check a "latest updated date" somewhere (a record in Firestore, a file in Cloud Storage, an entry in CLoud SQL,...) and compare it with your model updated date. If similar, great. If not, reload the latest model

You have several solutions, all depend on your wish.

---

But you have another solution, my preference. In fact, every time that you have a new model, recreate a new container with the new model already loaded in it (with Cloud Build) and deploy that new container on Cloud Run.

That solution solves your cache management issue, and you will have a better cold start latency for all your new instances. (In addition of easier roll back, A/B testing or canary release capability, version management and control, portability, local/other env testing,...)

Comment: These are all great suggestions. I think I will pursue creating a new container after making a new model. Thank you for your input.